# How to enable node-gyp parallel builds?

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

In my node module I use larger library in source code which takes a while to compile. I believe this has to do with the `--no-parallel` setting used by default by node-gyp. Now I wonder if it is possible to make node-gyp compile cpp files in parallel to speed up this process. I couldn't find anything that would help on the [GYP format reference page](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp/+/md-pages/docs/InputFormatReference.md). Is there a setting for my project gyp file or a hack for node-gyp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply add this to your package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
  "install": "node-gyp rebuild -j max"
},
```

This is cross-platform (contrary to using `env JOBS=` which does not work in `cmd` as an example)

`max` ensures using all the available threads. If you don't want to use all your CPU capacity specify a specific number of threads instead of `max`.

Comment: For manual builds from the command line, `node-gyp build -j 8` also works as you'd expect.  Unlike GNU Make, `-j8` doesn't do anything though, not even a warning.  Pretty poor command-line arg handling :/

Answer (score 11):

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/f6eab1f9e4b160b60b2736bb01a09c83785ba979/lib/build.js#L34), this might also work:

```
$ env JOBS=8 npm install ...
```

Comment: True, you can set an environment option, but I'd really prefer an option in the gyp file, so that it would work in all situations (for the dev, in Travis or other CI env and in particular for your users).

Comment: @MikeLischke how do you trigger the build? In my experience with native modules, you'd add a `build` script to `package.json`, which could also include the environment variable (`"build" : "env JOBS=8 node-gyp ..."`).

Comment: For Travis I tried the install: option and this ran my command, only to give an error that I cannot find node-gyp. But maybe I should try the build: option then?

Comment: @MikeLischke my experience with Travis is pretty limited.